# Есть ли способ вернуть одинаковое количество данных, когда условие работает с массивом?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, select

У меня есть 2 запроса.

```
select * from TABLE_A where id = 1 limit 10;

select * from TABLE_A where id = 2 limit 10;
```

Я хочу объединить таким образом:

```
select * from TABLE_A where id in (1,2) limit 20;
```

Чтобы возвращало одинаковое количество данных для `id=1` и `id=2`, но не больше 10 для каждого элемента массива, если для одного из них будет меньше данных.

Я не знаю, тривиальная ли это задача и возможно ли сделать так, как я хочу.

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TABLE_A where id in (1,2) limit 20;
```

Данным запросом говорится, что мы хотим выбрать не более двадцати записей со значением id равным 1 или 2. И не важно какое количество со значением 1 или со значением 2, главное не более двадцати. Но нам нужно сказать, что мы хотим выбрать не более десяти записей со значением 1 и не более десяти записей со значением 2. Для такого запроса необходим уникальный номер записи.

```
select * from  test where 
 rec_id in ( SELECT * FROM (select rec_id from test where id = 25 limit 10) as a) 
or 
 rec_id in ( SELECT * FROM (select rec_id from test where id = 34 limit 10) as b)
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ijK1FLhFB3tRMCdL75gNRb/3

Таким запросом мы говорим, что хотим выбрать не более десяти записей с id = 25 или не более десяти записей с id = 34.

> и не больше 10 для каждого елемента массива если для одного из них
>   будет меньше данных

Если записей с одним из id будет меньше десяти, то будут выбраны соответственно столько записей, сколько есть для одного id и не больше десяти для другого.

Например есть следующий набор данных:

```
IDWord  IDLanguage  word
1   25  антология
2   25  горка
3   34  бездарність
4   34  колірність
5   34  моралізм
6   34  промоїна
7   34  сирена
8   34  тернівка
9   25  синатра
10  25  стоп
11  25  уланова
12  34  домувальник
13  34  кльош
14  34  колористка
15  34  лемберг
16  34  ольга
17  34  полискування
18  34  тугаї
19  25  вирник
20  25  добавок
21  25  запруда
22  25  монровия
23  25  эванс
24  34  вибучування
25  34  лубок
26  34  научіння
27  25  астат
28  25  гарибальди
29  25  иезуитка
30  34  джиммі
31  34  наводнюваність
32  34  обновленість
33  34  обстоювання
34  34  уряд
35  25  аншлюс
36  25  переселенец
37  25  смехова
38  25  тяжеловоз
39  34  дирчання
40  34  дитинча
41  34  карбофос
42  34  карнавка
43  34  примушення
44  34  смєхов
45  34  специфікація
46  34  текемет
47  25  алабян
48  25  небытие
49  25  эйве
50  34  амбрит
51  34  амортизатор
52  34  базаринка
53  34  викривляння
54  34  карбоксилаза
55  34  педагогія
56  34  стоянов
57  25  алтаец
58  25  вьюн
59  25  сом
60  25  шатание
61  25  элиза
62  34  лапландія
63  25  журьба
64  25  насмешка
65  25  порядок
66  25  токсикология
67  34  антропофіл
68  34  ахіллодинія
69  34  вибивальник
70  34  деймос
71  34  еволюціоніст
72  34  імпресаріо
73  34  пальмітат
74  34  рейсшина
75  25  адомайтис
76  25  калинин
77  25  родонит
78  34  айкініт
79  34  бронза
80  34  мелітополь
81  25  альгамбра
```

Запросом `select IDWord from Words where IDLanguage = 25 limit 10` будут выбраны 10 IDWord для записей с IDLanguage = 25.

```
1
2
9
10
11
19
20
21
22
23
```

Запросом `select IDWord from Words where IDLanguage = 34 limit 10` будут выбраны 10 IDWord для записей с IDLanguage = 34.

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
12
13
14
15
```

Соответственно в общем запросе будут выбраны все записи с с вышеуказанными идентификаторами.

```
IDWord  IDLanguage  word
1   25  антология
2   25  горка
9   25  синатра
10  25  стоп
11  25  уланова
19  25  вирник
20  25  добавок
21  25  запруда
22  25  монровия
23  25  эванс
3   34  бездарність
4   34  колірність
5   34  моралізм
6   34  промоїна
7   34  сирена
8   34  тернівка
12  34  домувальник
13  34  кльош
14  34  колористка
15  34  лемберг
```

Comment: В вопросе говорится про `одинаковое количество данных` по обоим `id`.  У Вас это не выполняется. Лимит 10 - это второе условие.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Интересно с чего Вы взяли. что условие `одинаковое количество данных` не выполняется? Обоснуйте почему Вы так решили?

Comment: Cейчас попытался промоделировать Ваш ответ на https://www.db-fiddle.com/ и https://dbfiddle.uk - Обе отвечают:  `Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'` На какой версии MySQL Вы тестировали свой ответ?

Comment: А если записей с `IDLanguage = 25` в таблице только 5, что будем делать?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Если не поддерживается `LIMT` используйте `TOP`. И запрос `select IDWord from Words where IDLanguage = 34 limit 10` вернет столько  записей сколько есть в таблице. 5 есть значит 5.

Comment: `Top`, значит? Понятненько. Так на каком SQL Вы свой ответ тестировали? Или так, из головы пишете? MySQL, вообще-то `TOP` не поддерживает... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Мне тоже любопытно откуда Вы взяли ошибку  `MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT'`? Я проверил запрос на https://www.db-fiddle.com/ LIMIT поддерживается нормально. Версия 5.7

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92280/discussion-between-sergey-nudnov-and-andrey-sv).

Answer (score 0):

Мой ответ такой (смотрите также на [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3twgEKnRT2nhy9s5g21GSz/8)) - исправлен в соответствии с замечаниями **@AndreySv**.

- Запрос `q` добавляет к таблице счетчик строк `row_number` для каждого из встречающихся `id`;
- Запрос `q2` считает количество записей `mycount` в таблице для каждого `id`, который нам нужен, по-отдельности и выбирает минимальное значение `mycount`. Это позволяет обеспечить одинаковое количество записей, возвращенных для каждого интересующего `id`
- Условие `WHERE` основного запроса обеспечивает количество записей для каждого интересующего нас `id` не более 10 и не более минимального значения `mycount`

---

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE_A t
JOIN
(
  SELECT t1.*, count(*) as row_number 
  FROM TABLE_A t1
  JOIN TABLE_A t2
  ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.record >= t2.record
  GROUP BY t1.id, t1.record
) q
ON t.id = q.id AND t.record = q.record
WHERE q.row_number <= 10 AND q.row_number <= (
  SELECT MIN(mycount) as qty
  FROM
  (
    SELECT count(id) as mycount
    FROM TABLE_A
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT count(id) as mycount
    FROM TABLE_A
    WHERE id = 2
  ) q2
) AND t.id in (1,2)
```

Для тестового задания:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (
  id INT,
  record INT
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (id, record) 
VALUES 
(1, 101),
(1, 102),
(1, 103),
(1, 104),
(1, 105),
(1, 106),
(1, 107),
(1, 108),
(1, 109),
(1, 110),
(1, 111),
(1, 112),
(1, 113),
(2, 201),
(2, 202),
(2, 203),
(2, 204),
(2, 205);
```

Возвращает ответ:

```
id  record
1   101
1   102
1   103
1   104
1   105
2   201
2   202
2   203
2   204
2   205
```

Comment: У Вас равенство не работает если будет выбран несуществующий id например 4. При этом id 1 почему то девять а не десять записей, а там  <= 10 надо поставить

Comment: @AndreySv `< 10` - это опечатка, я ее и сам заметил, но в окончательном варианте она осталась не исправленной. А вот насчет несуществующего `id` - пришлось доработать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Взгляните на такой вариант запроса:

```
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE TABLE_A.id=1 LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE TABLE_A.id=2 LIMIT 10)
```